# Problema con búsqueda en formulario. (HTML + PHP + mySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, base-de-datos

Tengo una *Database* llamada `productos`, y necesito buscar elementos dentro de ella, para ser más específico, lo que escribí en un *TextBox* llamado `search`.
Para eso, escribí esta porción de código:

```
<?php

  include "conexionDB.php";
  $where="";
  $nombre_producto=$_POST["search"];
  $town=$_POST["ciudad"];
  $category=$_POST["categoria"];
  $precioMin=$_POST["txt_min"];
  $precioMax=$_POST["txt_max"];

  if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){
    if(empty($_POST['ciudad']) and (empty($_POST['categoria'])) and (empty($_POST['txt_min'])) and (empty($_POST['txt_max'])) ){
      $consulta_mysql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE (`nombre` or `descripcion`  like '%$nombre_producto%') order by `id` DESC "); //si todo está vacío
    }else if(empty($_POST['ciudad']) and (empty($_POST['categoria']))){
      $consulta_mysql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE (`nombre` or `descripcion`  like '%$nombre_producto%') or `precio` BETWEEN '$precioMin' AND '$precioMax' order by `id` DESC ");

    }else if(empty($_POST['ciudad'])) {
      $consulta_mysql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE (`nombre` or `descripcion`  like '%$nombre_producto%') or `precio` BETWEEN '$precioMin' AND '$precioMax' AND `categoria` = '$category' order by `id` DESC ");//si está vacío el comboBox de ciudad
    }else if (empty($_POST['categoria'])) {
      $consulta_mysql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE (`nombre` or `descripcion`  like '%$nombre_producto%') and `precio` BETWEEN '$precioMin' AND '$precioMax' AND  `ciudad` = '$town' order by `id` DESC ");// si está vacío el comboBox de categoría
    }else if(empty($_POST['search'])and(empty($_POST['category']))and(empty($_POST['txt_min']))and(empty($_POST['txt_max']))){
       $consulta_mysql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `ciudad` = '$town' order by `id` DESC");

    }else{
       $consulta_mysql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE (`nombre` or `descripcion`  like '%$nombre_producto%') AND `precio` BETWEEN '$precioMin' AND '$precioMax' AND `categoria` = '$category' AND `ciudad` = '$town' order by `id` DESC ");
      }
  }
?>
```

No tengo problemas de *SQL*, ni me tira ninguna alerta, pero, la búsqueda no arroja ningún resultado.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: consulta cuando lo ejecutas en el navegador te muestra algun error ?

Comment: Ninguno! De hecho, cuando hago uso de las demás características que programé (precio mínimo, máximo, ciudad), la búsqueda arroja resultados, pero cuando decides insertar texto en el textbox... nada de nada.

Comment: Puedes ver lo que estoy intentando hacer en http://www.wefindit.ml

Comment: @Pierro acabo de descubrir que la búsqueda funciona sólo cuando el contenido de `search` coincide con el campo `descripcion` en la base de datos.

Comment: prueba en vez de poner else if a todos ponle if  y prueba

Comment: Al quitarle el `else if`a todos, deja de funcionar.

Comment: Puedes poner un echo y mirar a que parte del if te está entrando. Será mucho más fácil debuggear el código así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las SELECTs están mal. Haces los OR de manera incorrecta y el resultado no va a ser lo que esperas. Por ejemplo, tienes esto (estilizado para que se vea mejor):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `productos` 
WHERE (`nombre` or `descripcion`  like '%$nombre_producto%') 
order by `id` DESC
```

Parece que lo que quieres es que te devuelva los productos cuyo nombre o descripción contengan el nombre del producto (`$nombre_producto`), pero así no es como funcionan los OR en SQL. Debes comparar cada campo individualmente, algo como esto:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `productos` 
WHERE `nombre` like '%$nombre_producto%' or 
      `descripcion` like '%$nombre_producto%' 
order by `id` DESC
```

De lo contrario, puede que la consulta SQL no te de fallo, pero va a estar mal porque no te devolverá lo que esperas.

Como nota aparte: **el código que compartes es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL**, debes sanear siempre las entradas de usuario y usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de crear sentencias SQL dinámicas (otro problema que tienen es que si el nombre tiene comillas simples, se romperá la consulta).